# QGIS - from shapefile to (X,Y) coordinates (latitude and longitude

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, stata

I'm currently working in a project (in state) using QGIS, for which I want to measure distances between points. I have a map, from Swedish electoral districts with a specific reference: SWEREF99 TM. The polygons and points are not in latitude and longitude.

How do I transform this projection into a latitude and longitude one?

Comment: Have you read the official tutorial on [`reprojecting layers`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html)? If so, what is left unclear?

Comment: Be aware that distances in degree are virtually useless.

Comment: Could you add some more information on which version of QGIS you're using and on which OS? Are you looking for an answer on how to reproject your layer or how to measure points? Please clarify you question a bit

Comment: You ask how to measure or how to get lat/lon? These are completely different things. Use ellipsoidal distance for measurements.

Comment: SWEREF99 TM ([EPSG:3006](https://epsg.io/3006)) is Sweden's projected coordinate system, and will be far better for measuring distances than latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in QGIS, use `reproject layer` (under vector general in your toolbox), if you are in ArcGIS, use `project` (under data management tools > projection and transformation in your toolbox). Use WGS84 (also known as ESPG:4326) as the destination/output projection. you are currently using EPSG:3006 not EPSG:4326.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to Settings -> Options there is a Default Datum Transformation tool, where you can change the meassure unit

Comment: that is reprojecting the canvas, not the layer.